# Interesting Ways to Find the value of Pi

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, pi

Is there any interesting ways to find pi?

Thanks.

Comment: @Joe: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html, $(3, 1, 4) \equiv (1, 5, 9) + (2, 6, 5) \pmod{10}$.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Approximations_of_%CF%80#) are a lot of interesting ways.

Comment: Some of the fastest converging summations:  http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/monthly567-587.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try the Gregory Series, It uses a sequence to find the value of Pi

Comment: I hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

$$ \pi =  \sqrt{6(1 + \frac 1{2^2} + \frac 1{3^2} + \frac 1{4^2} + \frac 1{5^2}...)}$$